# How to update in INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger for view, created for linked tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have tables **Group** and **Role**, linked with a foreign key. I need to update them through a view, so I have to write INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger. My current solution is wrong and I don't know how to fix it. How should I fix it?

Table **Group**

```
CREATE TABLE [Group]
(
    groupId   INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    groupName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    picture   IMAGE       NULL,
    CONSTRAINT UniqueGroupName UNIQUE (groupName)
)
```

Table **Role**

```
CREATE TABLE Role
(
    roleName VARCHAR(50),
    groupId  INT,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Group FOREIGN KEY (groupId) REFERENCES [Group] (groupId),
    PRIMARY KEY (roleName, groupId),
    canBan   TINYINT DEFAULT (0) /* 0 or 1 */
)
```

View

```
CREATE VIEW GroupRoleView AS
SELECT g.groupName, r.roleName, r.canBan
FROM [Group] as g
         INNER JOIN Role AS r ON g.groupId = r.groupId
GO
```

Current trigger, which is not correct

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateGroupRoleViewTrigger
    ON GroupRoleView
    INSTEAD OF UPDATE
    AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tempTable TABLE
                       (
                           groupId       VARCHAR(50),
                           roleName   VARCHAR(50),
                           oldBanAbility TINYINT,
                           newBanAbility TINYINT
                       )
    INSERT INTO @tempTable (groupId, roleName, oldBanAbility, newBanAbility)
    SELECT g.groupId, deleted.roleName, deleted.canBan, inserted.canBan
    FROM deleted
             INNER JOIN inserted ON deleted.groupName = inserted.groupName
             LEFT JOIN [Group] as g on deleted.groupName = g.groupName
    SELECT * FROM @tempTable
    IF (UPDATE(roleName) OR UPDATE(groupName))
        THROW 50003, 'You cannot move role between groups or change role name. Delete existing role and create a new one instead of this.', 1
    IF (UPDATE(canBan))
        BEGIN
            --todo
            UPDATE Role
            SET canBan = (SELECT TOP 1 newBanAbility FROM @tempTable)
            WHERE groupId IN (SELECT groupId FROM @tempTable)
              AND roleName IN (SELECT roleName FROM @tempTable)
            SELECT * FROM deleted
 
        end
end
GO
```

Comment: "My current solution is wrong" and "is not correct" don't give us much to go on. Could you be a little more vague? Divide-by-zero? Server reboots? Nothing happens? Aside: The [`update()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) returns `true` if a column is written to in an `update` statement regardless of whether the value is altered, e.g. `update ... set roleName = roleName ...;`.

Comment: `CREATE TRIGGER UpdateGroupRoleViewTrigger ON GroupRoleViewForTrigger INSTEAD OF UPDATE`? Typo maybe?

Answer (score 1):

By the looks of things you have fallen into the [classic trap](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/) of assuming there is only one row in the trigger table.
Note also that triggers ignore `BEGIN` \ `END` for marking the end of the trigger, so any code after that in your batch is still included. End the trigger with `GO`.
Furthermore, as mentioned in comments, you are not checking whether the values have changed.
You are also missing the join check against roleName in the deleted/inserted query.

Your `UPDATE` statement is also not doing joins correctly, and in this case you do not need a temp table at all.

This is the correct version:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateGroupRoleViewTrigger
    ON GroupRoleView
    INSTEAD OF UPDATE
    AS

    IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted))    -- early bail-out
        RETURN;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;    -- prevent confusion when checking rows updated in client

    IF (EXISTS (
        SELECT roleName, groupName FROM inserted
        EXCEPT
        SELECT roleName, groupName FROM deleted))
        THROW 50003, 'You cannot move role between groups or change role name. Delete existing role and create a new one instead of this.', 1;


    IF (UPDATE(canBan))
    BEGIN
        --todo
        UPDATE r
        SET canBan = i.canBan
        FROM deleted d
        -- added rolename equi-join as that appears to be correct from the schema
        INNER JOIN inserted i ON d.groupName = i.groupName AND d.roleName = i.roleName
            AND d.canBan <> i.canBan
        INNER JOIN Role r ON r.groupName = i.groupName AND r.roleName = i.roleName
    END;

GO
```

---

**However...**

SQL Server actually supports [updatable views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#updatable-views), so you actually don't need a trigger here at all. You should be able to just update the view directly, so long as all the columns are in one table.

Comment: Aside: I'd suggest using `if not exists ( select 42 from inserted )` (or `deleted`) rather than `if @@RowCount = 0` for a "bail-out" check. `@@RowCount` is "fragile", i.e. it's easy to add a statement that changes the value in the trigger without realizing the implications, there may be other triggers that execute before this trigger, `merge` sets the value in ways you might not expect, ... . In most cases there shouldn't be a need to check, i.e. a lightweight trigger and relatively few statements that affect zero rows.

Comment: I think `@@ROWCOUNT` is faster but not sure. I don't believe other triggers affect `@@ROWCOUNT`, I could be wrong. Anyone who edits a trigger with `@@ROWCOUNT = 0` like that would lose their job where I come from. `MERGE`: true, it means you won't bail-out, but who cares, the rest is still correct code. Depends if anyone actually uses `MERGE` on the table.

Comment: @HABO just repro'd, and no, `@@ROWCOUNT` will always be the value of the outer DML. Another trigger does not affect it at all. By the way, is there any reason you did not vote my answer up or down?

Comment: I've learned to trust documentation, at least as far as I can throw it. A test is nice, but not a guarantee. A quick test on my ancient laptop put `@@RowCount` at about 2.2μs vs. `exists` at about 3.5μs. That's a penalty I'm willing to pay for what I feel is clearer and more robust code. (Having done industrial automation one hates to be wrong when shuttling around a ladle of molten steel.) A "mistake" as small as someone adding or moving `set nocount on;` to the beginning of every trigger would cause all of the triggers to exit early as it sets `@@RowCount` to `0`.

Comment: Your answer repeats the OP's error in `IF (UPDATE(roleName) OR UPDATE(groupName))` which does not check for changed values, just for columns that are written. Aside: It took a long time for Microsoft to correct the documentation to explain why `select 30 / 3 / 5;` works and `select 30 / -3 / 5;` doesn't. Both work on every other SQL database I've tried and I'm pretty sure that M$ violates the ISO SQL Standard.

Comment: Good point about `SET NOCOUNT ON`, I thought `SET` statements didn't reset `@@ROWCOUNT `. I will change it on that basis because that's one statement no-one would think about. `IF (UPDATE( ` is a legit early bail-out so long as you also check the `inserted` and `deleted`, which I do.

Comment: Sorry just realised you meant the first check. It's hard to argue against that, because it's a Primary Key and he doesn't want that changed, so there is no reason to allow it in an `UPDATE` statement anyway

Answer (score 0):

Well, just got an idea to try to write it all on a piece of paper, and in helped me. Tomorrow  will check it (by demonstrating to teacher), but for now, I think, that this **UPDATE** statement with joins is correct

@charsieface 's answer also helped me, except for the moment, that table ***Role*** has no field ***groupName***, but only ***groupId***

```
UPDATE Role
set canBan = i.canBan
FROM deleted d
INNER JOIN inserted i ON d.groupName = i.groupName AND d.roleName = i.roleName
    AND d.canBan <> i.canBan
INNER JOIN [Group] g ON g.groupName = i.groupName
INNER JOIN Role r on g.groupId = r.groupId AND i.roleName = r.roleName
```